# How do it know which version/commit of my source is running in AppEngine

Tags: git, google-app-engine, svn

In AppEngine, how do I know which version/commit of my source is running currently? I would like it if AppEngine either take note of my source control's commit-hash (in git), version (in svn) or something. OR I could update version in a checked-in file and that's shown (like an Android manifest version). I've not found any good answers in AppEngine docs or SO postings.

Background: For simple apps one can assume that the developer always deploys the latest code to AppEngine. But the developer could forget. Or there could be multiple developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update appengine-web.xml file with whatever version number that you need during each deploy, and then you can see which version is running in the App Engine console.

If you want the version to be visible within an app, you have to implement it yourself. For example, you can make a quick call to your app engine instance to get a version number:

```
@Override
public String readVersionNumber() {
    return SystemProperty.applicationVersion.get();
}
```